# Read XML file using LinQ

Tags: linq

I have one xml file. That xml file have multiple elements. I want to read these elements and bind into datagrid using Linq in C#.

Comment: This question is not specific enough for an answer.  Please add more details.

Comment: 30 questions, 0 accepted answers, 1 upvote, you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/faq before asking other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably be better served using [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)/[DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) for this binding.  But if you want to use LINQ 2 XML you could do something like this...

```
var xml = XElement.Load("yourfile.xml");
var records = from element in xml.Elements()
              let col1 = element.Element("element1").Value
              let col2 = element.Element("element2").Value
              let col3 = element.Attribute("attribute1").Value
              select new {
                  col1,
                  col2
                  col3
              }
```

... note there are several spots where you could get NullReferenceExceptions in the above query.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use DataSet.ReadXml()  and then bind it into DataGrid?